# C++ Dynamic Array: A value of type "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

I am working on a C++ project for school in which the program will read in a list of numbers from a text file, store them in a dynamic array, then print them out to another text file. To be honest I'm a little lost with the pointers in this, and I am getting the error "A value of type "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"" in my main source file.

Main.cpp (this is where I'm getting the error):

```
#include "dynamic.h"

int main
{
    readDynamicData("input.txt","output.txt");
}
```

dynamic.cpp (the skeleton for the program):

```
#include "dynamic.h"


void readDynamicData(string input, string output)
{
    DynamicArray da; //struct in the header file
    da.count = 0;
    da.size = 5; //initial array size of 5

    int *temp = da.theArray;
    da.theArray = new int[da.size];


    ifstream in(input);
    ofstream out(output);

    in >> da.number; //prime read
    while (!in.fail())
    {
        if (da.count < da.size)
        {
            da.theArray[da.count] = da.number;
            da.count++;
            in >> da.number; //reprime
        }
        else grow; //if there are more numbers than the array size, grow the array
    }


    out << "Size: " << da.size << endl;
    out << "Count: " << da.count << endl;
    out << "Data:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < da.size; i++)
        out << da.theArray[i];

    in.close();
    out.close();

    delete[] temp;
}


void grow(DynamicArray &da) //this portion was given to us
{
    int *temp = da.theArray;
    da.theArray = new int[da.size * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i<da.size; i++)
        da.theArray[i] = temp[i];
    delete[] temp;
    da.size = da.size * 2;
}
```

and dynamic.h, the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#ifndef _DynamicArray_
#define _DynamicArray_


using namespace std;

void readDynamicData(string input, string output);

struct DynamicArray
{
    int *theArray;
    int count;
    int size;
    int number;
};

void grow(DynamicArray &da);

#endif
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I apogolize, but Im not sure why this does not qualify as minimal and complete? I'm not sure why the error was triggered, so I posted the entire code as it code be in any of the three files. Please let me know if this is not true

Comment: `using namespace std` in header files is such bad thing

Comment: You can certainly narrow this down to a more minimal example. Reading your compiler output carefully will be helpful.

Comment: Have you even bothered to read up on how to write or call a function?

Comment: I have, and I've written quite a few (albeit simple) programs, this was just a case of staring at something too long and missing the most obvious typo with the main()

Answer (score 0):

`main` is a function so it needs brackets:

```
int main(){
    // your code
    return 0; // because it should return intiger
}
```

And. Your `grow` is also a function, so if you want to call it you write `grow()` and it needs `DynamicArray` as a parameter.

It is impossible to write working programs on <s>C/C++</s> any programming language not knowing a basic syntax.

Comment: An explicit `return 0` is not required in `main`, which means that the above "because it needs..." comment is not really accurate. No, it doesn't really need it.

Comment: Wow, that was a straight typo with the main, not sure I possibly missed the missing (), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add parenthesis to main or any function:

```
int main(){/*your code here ...*/};
```

2- you are using an unitialized objct:

```
DynamicArray da; //struct in the header file
da.count = 0;
da.size = 5; //initial array size of 5
```

so int* theArray is a member data and is uninitialized so welcome to a segfault

all the members of da are not initialized so you have to do before using it.

3- also you add parenthesis to grow function:

```
else grow(/*some parameter here*/); // grow is a function
```

4- `using namespace std;` in a header file is a very bad practice.
tip use it inside source

5- why making inclusion of iostream and string.. before the inclusion guard??
correct it to:

```
#ifndef _DynamicArray_
#define _DynamicArray_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

/*your code here*/

#endif
```